# Bug in SQL Server MERGE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a `MERGE` statement. If the record exists, update it. If it doesn't exist, insert it.

This query runs, but is says '0 rows affected'. I know that an add_id of '3' does not exist, so I would expect it to insert a row. What am I doing wrong? Sorry, I've never written a merge query before.

```
MERGE INTO dbo.delay AS TARGET 
USING (SELECT * FROM dbo.delay WHERE add_id = 3) AS SOURCE ON (Source.add_id = Target.add_id)

WHEN MATCHED 
   THEN UPDATE SET my_value = 22 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
   THEN INSERT (add_id, my_value) VALUES (1, 22);
```

Comment: There are no rows in `delay` with an id of "3".  With no data in the source table, nothing is merged in.

Comment: I guess I'm confused on how it's supposed to work.  I was hoping for upsert functionality without having to check a table for a record and then either updating or inserting...

Comment: You perhaps want something like `merge into dbo.delay as target using (select add_id = 3) as source on source.add_id = target.add_id...` It might help to think of a merge as being somewhat similar to a join. With no rows in the source, it inserts nothing.

Comment: ZLK - that nailed it.  If you put it into the form of an answer I'll mark it as the correct solution.  Thank you!!!!